# 2D vector ignores assigned values?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I'm working on a simple class representing polynomials. I store coefficients and equivalent powers of x in 2D vector. The way of assigning certain terms must be as shown in the test file. It equires some operator overloading which i provided. The problem is that it assigns proper coefficients besides last one, additionally every terms has power of x of the first assigned value.

**Desired output:**

Polynomial p1: 2x^3 + 3.6x + 7x^0

Polynomial p2: 3x^1 + 6x^2 + 1x^4

**Actual output:**

Polynomial p1: 5x^3 + 2x^3 + 3.6x^3

Polynomial p2: 5x^1 +  3x^1 + 6x^1

Have you got any idea what is the case? I

**Polynomials.cpp**

```
double & Polynomials::operator[]( int power_of_x ){


    this->coeff_and_power.push_back(5.0);  // dummy variable 5.0 just to alloc 'cell' for coefficient

    this->coeff_and_power.push_back( (double) power_of_x ); //assigning power of x

    this->polynomial_terms.push_back( coeff_and_power );    // polynomial_terms vector contains collection of 2 elements vectors( coefficient and power ) indicating certain term of a function


    return (coeff_and_power[0]);  //coefficient to be assigned in main(returning by reference) function
}



std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Polynomials & toWrite){


    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < toWrite.polynomial_terms.size(); i++){

            if(i){
                out<<" + ";
            }

            out<<toWrite.polynomial_terms[i][0]<<"x^"<<toWrite.polynomial_terms[i][1];          
    }

    return out;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polynomials.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

Polynomials p1;                             
p1[3] = 2; p1[1] = 3.6; p1[0] = 7;                

Polynomials p2;                            
p2[1] = 3; p2[2] = 6; p2[4] = 1;                 

cout << "Polynomial p1: " << p1 << endl;              
cout << "Polynomial p2: " << p2 << endl;
```

}

Comment: Use a debugger and step through it line by line.

Comment: why do i get nagative rates? The solution is so obvious or what?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The downvotes may accumulate because you don't give us a chance to reproduce the error; e.g. in my answer I have to do some guessing work and risk that I earn downvotes on that answer because I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your `operator[]` overload you `push_back()`, but unconditionally.

```
return coeff_and_power[0];
```

return `front` for assignment

And btw this

```
this->polynomial_terms.push_back( coeff_and_power )
```

pushes a copy, not a reference, given `polynomial_terms` has behavior like e.g. std:vector.